# Spring 3 Task Scheduling via Annotations running multiple instances at same time on server

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

I am using spring scheduler for scheduling job.
It is working fine in local but on server it is running multiple times for same instance.

Log from server

```
20 Mar 2014 09:00:00 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  com.yourkey.jobs.GetDeviceStatusJob  - *** No Lost Devices ***
20 Mar 2014 09:00:00 [pool-5-thread-1] INFO  com.yourkey.jobs.GetDeviceStatusJob  - *** No Lost Devices ***
20 Mar 2014 09:00:00 [pool-4-thread-1] INFO  com.yourkey.jobs.GetDeviceStatusJob  - *** No Lost Devices ***
```

applicationcontext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"

xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    -------------------------------------
    -------------------------------------

    <task:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="syncBrandOffersJob" class="com.yourkey.jobs.SyncBrandOffersJob"></bean>
    <bean id="getDeviceStatusJob" class="com.yourkey.jobs.GetDeviceStatusJob"></bean>


</beans>
```

GetDeviceStatusJob.java

```
@Service
public class GetDeviceStatusJob {

private static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(GetDeviceStatusJob.class);

@Autowired
private DeviceService deviceService;

public DeviceService getDeviceService() {
    return deviceService;
}

public void setDeviceService(DeviceService deviceService) {
    this.deviceService = deviceService;
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/10 * * * ?")
public void getLostDeviceInfo() {
    List<Device> deviceList = deviceService.getAllLostDevices();
    if (deviceList != null && !deviceList.isEmpty()) {
        for (Device device : deviceList) {
            String gcmRegistrationId = device.getGcmRegistrationId();
            if (gcmRegistrationId != null) {
                String status = null;
                if (device.isStatus()) {
                    status = "LOST";
                } else {
                    status = "Active";
                }
                String message = device.getMessage();

                String jsonString = "{\"status\":\"" + status
                        + "\",\"message\":\"" + message
                        + "\",\"registration_ids\" : [\""
                        + gcmRegistrationId + "\"]}";
                System.out.println(jsonString);
                NetClientUtil.httpGcmPostClient(jsonString,
                        "getLostDeviceInfo");
            }else{
                logger.info("**** gcmRegistrationId not present for device" + device.getId());
            }
        }
    }else{
        logger.info("*** No Lost Devices ***");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please see the logs..you can see same job GetDeviceStatusJob  running thrice at same time.

Comment: You define your bean in XML and also annotate with @Service. Are you sure you don't create actually 3 instances of this class in different contexts?

Comment: I am sure that I am not creating any more instance.but yes I can remove bean instance from xml.Its an error I feel .I ll remove it but don't think it ll make any difference

Comment: I think both service and bean together were creating problem.now I am observing logs it is pretty stable.

Answer (score 2):

As @MaciejWalkowiak said, and as the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) says,

> Make sure that you are not initializing multiple instances of the same
>   @Scheduled annotation class at runtime, unless you do want to schedule
>   callbacks to each such instance. Related to this, make sure that you
>   do not use @Configurable on bean classes which are annotated with
>   @Scheduled and registered as regular Spring beans with the container:
>   You would get double initialization otherwise, once through the
>   container and once through the @Configurable aspect, with the
>   consequence of each @Scheduled method being invoked twice.

Log `this` in your job. If it's the same instance, the scheduling is getting triggered incorrectly somehow. If not, you're instantiating the scheduled class three times.

**Update**: I thought about this a bit more since you said it's environment-specific, and noticed that the thread pool names are different, but they're all thread 1 in their respective pools. That implies you have multiple `ThreadPoolTaskExecutors`. Are you creating multiple containers somehow?

Comment: yes,if you see code you will see that i had used @service over class and <bean> in application context.I feel that was creating problem.now as i had remove bean def from appcontext its working good